# SFTP: Couldn't get handle: No such file or directory, randomly occurs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, sftp

I'm getting  "Couldn't get handle: No such file or directory" error while transferring the file from a unix application as mentioned in below sample script, We are getting this error randomly but most of the time the file transfer is successful.  I couldn't find what is causing the failure sometimes.

ABCCouldn't get handle: No such file or directory

//script1:

```
export HOST=server.abc.com
export ACCOUNT=ABC-application
LOGFILE=abc.log
LOGDIR=/directory1/directory2/logdir
DIR=/directory1/directory2/scriptdir
sftp -b ${DIR}/sftpscript.sftp -oPort=222 ${ACCOUNT}@${HOST} >> ${LOGDIR}/${LOGFILE}

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo SFTP  failed >> ${LOGDIR}/${LOGFILE}
 cat ${LOGDIR}/${LOGFILE}
 exit 1
fi
```

//sftpscript.sftp

```
cd destination_Dir
lcd /directory1/directory2/sourcefiledir
put abcsource.dat abcdest.txt
bye
```

can anyone please let me know what causing the failure sometimes.  Will modifying Verbosity of sftp command would work ?

Comment: We got the same error today after the modification, do you know what is the cause for Couldn't get handle: No such file or directory